# Selecting Records Matching Two or More Related Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 'persons' table:

```
person_id    name

100          jack

125          jill

201          jane
```

And many sub-tables, that the person_id could be in:

'rowing'

```
id    person_id

1     100

2     201
```

'swimming'

```
id    person_id

1     125

2     201
```

'running'

```
id    person_id
1     201
```

'throwing'

```
id    person_id

1     125

2     201
```

I would like to be able to select all people who are involved in two activities, regardless of which two.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you should use only one relation table which has an `ActivityId` instead. Then you could use: `SELECT p.person_id FROM Persons p INNER JOIN PersonActivities pa ON p.person_id = pa.person_id GROUP BY p.person_id HAVING(COUNT(DISTINCT pa.ActivityId) >= 2)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: the last line does say "who are involved in two activities, regardless of which two" in my defense... ah well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the great @TimSchmelter (great first name) mentioned, you should really be having a single `PersonActivities` table with an id corresponding to the particular activity.

That being said, if you *must* work with your current schema, one option would be to `UNION` together the activity tables, and then count which persons have two or more records, meaning that they participated in two or more activities.

```
SELECT t1.person_id, t1.name
FROM persons
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.person_id, COUNT(t.person_id) AS activityCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT person_id FROM rowing
        UNION ALL
        SELECT person_id FROM swimming
        UNION ALL
        SELECT person_id FROM running
        UNION ALL
        SELECT person_id FROM throwing
    ) AS t
    GROUP BY t.person_id
    HAVING COUNT(t.person_id) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id
```

Comment: Just to point out, this isnt going to 100% work because the activity tables have a surrogate key and I dont think OP is forcing a unique constraint on the person_id in each of those tables. So rowing can have the same person twice, but +1 for the answer and your edit to use a better schema

Comment: You could add a "virtual" `ActivityName` or `ActivityId` column which you can use for the `GROUP BY`. For example: `... SELECT person_id, Activity='Rowing' FROM rowing
        UNION ALL
        SELECT person_id,Activity='Swimming' FROM swimming ...`